# How do you label a Launcher icon which has no icon label

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

How do you label a Launcher icon which has no icon label

For example I added gtkpod but I have a black square where an icon should be. How do I add an icon?

Comment: can you add the contents of the *.place you created? There should be an option in there that points to an icon. That's the icon it should show (if it is there on your disc).

Answer (score 2):

First you can try to reinstall it at the Software Center.

If it does not work, check `/usr/share/applications/gtkpod.desktop` it should look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=gtkpod iPod Manager
GenericName=iPod Manager
Comment=Manage music and video on an Apple iPod
Exec=gtkpod
Icon=gtkpod
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;AudioVideo;
```

If the file matches this one check if you have the gtkpod icon in your icon theme `/usr/share/icons/` should be under apps or devices.

Also if you have a custom `.desktop` for gtkpod in `~/.local/share/applications/` you can rename the file `foo-bar.old`, so the original file should work properly.

After you do everything above, just logout then back to restart unity.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click desktop -> ***Create Launcher...***
- Write a name
- Click ***browse*** next to the command and browse to the executable (most likely in /usr/bin).
- Write comment (optional)
- Click the ***little rocket icon*** to change the icon to whatever you like.
- Click OK
- Drag launcher to Unity bar.

Easier than creating .desktop files in my book, and works just as well.